# datagridview in webform c# show query in footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datagridview

I have two query's in C# running in a datagridview, one is to show all data. the other is set to display in the footer. The footer is showing, just not displaying my query.
**query one (with footer)**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", cs);
   cs.Open();
   MySqlDataReader dgl = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   dg.ShowFooter = true;
   dg.DataSource = dgl;
   dg.DataBind();
   cs.Close();
}
**query two(footer query)**
protected void dg_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", cs);
   cs.Open();
   String totalDonations = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
   cs.Close();
   dg.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = totalDonations;
}
```

the datagrid shows query one works well, the footer even shows but it has not got any data.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a control to display the return value of the second query...

Comment: hmm so dg.DataSource = dgl; ?

Comment: Well, you use the term 'footer' so I assume this is a webpage.  If you are trying to display your query, you would need something like a `label` on your web form to show that data, right?

Comment: hmm its the footer in the datagridview, im not to sure Brian. i shall give it a try

Comment: I thought `datagridviews` didn't support footers? I think what you really want here is a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It dose if you use it in web form

Comment: In webforms it is GridView, not datagridview.

Comment: thank you, can you see any errors in the code above and why it may not work ?

Comment: Hard to comment without looking at the markup. Make sure you have `ShowFooter="true"` for the gridview. I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: ive got dg.ShowFooter = true;   my foot is showing but its not displaying **query two(footer query)**

Comment: @Beep - Set a break point at `dg.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = totalDonations;` and see the value of `totalDonations`. Probably it is empty.

Comment: You can run the query in SSMS also, probably it will return null.

Comment: @afzalulh its not coming up with anything, but ive run the query and its fin so im not so sure.

Comment: Do like this: string totalDonation = string.Format("Donation:{0}", cmd.ExecuteScaler());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have it working, there are ways to improve it.

In the first method, using statement would manage the connection better:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //Assuming you have a connection string strConnect
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customer", con))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    dg.ShowFooter = true;
    dg.DataSource = dt;
    dg.DataBind();
}
```

And the second method:

```
protected void dg_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String totalDonations = string.Empty;
    //Assuming you have a connection string strConnect
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", con))
        {
            totalDonations = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }

    dg.FooterRow.Cells[3].Text = totalDonations;
}
```

Probably I would use GridView's RowDataBound to write into footer where I can can know the type of row:

```
protected void dg_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        String totalDonations = string.Empty;
        //Assuming you have a connection string strConnect
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnect))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", con))
            {
                totalDonations = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = totalDonations;
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Here's the markup I have used to test:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnDataBound="dg_DataBound" ShowFooter="true"> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I have tried it, changing it to MYSQL and adding my connection string and the rest. the grid view shows up but the footer data dose not. I will keep working on it a bit later and if it works il accept your answer. thanks again

Comment: Ahh...There's a typo in second sql... It should be Customer, not Custome

Comment: still not showing the footer data, il go through the code in a bit see if i can get it to work.

Comment: You can access the source I have used [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0ay1pd19YUmxZTEk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thank you have sent request benoats@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

After hours of problems, I have solved it.

```
corrected code


{
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", cs);
        MySqlCommand cmdtwo = new MySqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Donation) AS Total_Donation FROM Customer", cs);
        cs.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dgl = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dg.DataSource = dgl;
        dg.ShowFooter = true;
        dg.DataBind();
        cs.Close();
        cs.Open();
        string totalDonations = Convert.ToString(cmdtwo.ExecuteScalar());
        cs.Close();
        dg.FooterRow.Cells[7].Text = "Total £";
        dg.FooterRow.Cells[8].Text = totalDonations;
}
```

although I am sure there is a better way of doing this, if you know please feel free to edit.